# Interpretation of the Laplacian in exterior calculus

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

In exterior calculus, the $k$-form Laplacian operator is

$$\Delta:=\star d \star d+ d \star  d \star =\delta d+ d\delta $$

This operator applied to a $0$-form or function I believe is reduced to $\Delta:=\star d \star d.$

Say the function is $\phi,$ then $d\phi$ is the differential of the function, and the Hodge star of $d\phi$ in $\mathbb R^3$ is something that looks like

$$\text{something } dy\wedge dz + \text{something else } dz\wedge dx+ \text{other }dx\wedge dy$$

Are the coefficients just the partial derivatives of

$$d\phi=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}dy + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}dz$$

as in

$$\star d \phi=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x} dy\wedge dz + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y} dz\wedge dx+ \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}dx\wedge dy$$

?

Then applying $d$ on this last expression would produce

$$\begin{align}
d\star d \phi&=\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x}\right) dx\wedge dy\wedge dz + \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial y}\right) dy\wedge dz\wedge dx+ \frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\left(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial z}\right)dz\wedge dx\wedge dy\\
& =\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2} dx\wedge dy\wedge dz
\end{align}$$

If the preceding operations are correct, the last Hodge $\star$ would simple drop the wedges at the end of the expression to end up with a regular scalar function:

$$\star d \star d \phi=\nabla^2\phi=\frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2\phi}{\partial z^2} $$

> If all this is correct, how would that then extrapolate to $$\Delta:=\star d \star d+ d \star  d \star =\delta d+ d\delta ?$$

Comment: It doesn't. You would have to know at least how $\triangle$ acts on $1$-forms as well.

Comment: @IvoTerek "It doesn't" extrapolate? The assumptions on the exterior calculus operators acting on 0-forms in my post are correct? However, there is a big jump its application to 1-forms?

Comment: All of your computation seems correct to me, what I meant is that knowing that $\triangle =\star d\star d$ for $0$-forms does not imply that $\triangle =\star d \star d+d\star d\star$ for all $k$-forms. You need to know that this last expression holds for $k=1$ at least. Proving it directly for $1$-forms should not be that bad either.

Comment: I don't really understand your questions. If you call the operator $\Delta=\delta d + d\delta$ then this is the usual Hodge Laplacian. The Hodge  Laplacian is by itself an extrapolation of the Laplace-Beltrami operator,  which is just your usual Laplace operator  and in the case of $\mathbf{R}^n$ reduces to the usual operator from multivariable calculus $f\mapsto \sum_i \partial^2_i f$.